# Spotify sdk trackFromData method not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I have requested the current user and from the user have requested the saved tracks of the user. When making the call to the api it succeeds and I am able to convert the response into a Spotify track object, but when I access the fields of the object the values come back as the default values. I parsed this response in the same manner as I did to get the current user but it didn't work this time. Any ideas on the cause?

```
    let savedTracksRequestHeaders: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken!,
    ]

    let params = ["limit": "1"]

    var userSong = SPTTrack.init()

    Alamofire.request("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks", method: 
    .get, parameters: params, headers: 
    savedTracksRequestHeaders).responseJSON { response in
        print("Saved Track Response")
        debugPrint(response)

        do {
            // executes with no errors
            try userSong = SPTTrack.init(from: response.data, with: 
            response.response)
            print("user songs")
            // when the variable is used all fields are default 
            // values
            print(userSong.popularity)

        } catch is Error {
            print("load songs failed")
        }

    }
```